# Installing selectivizr library on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying to enable selectivizr module after installing it.  It requires me to upload selectivizr-min.js to sites/all/libraries/selectivizr or sites/all/modules/selectivizr/selectivizr.js and I did just that.

However, I keep getting this error:

Download it from http://selectivizr.com and copy into the selectivizr module directory or into the libraries directory if your are using the libraries module. For more information please read the README.txt (Currently using Selectivizr Library Missing)

Since I am not familiar with the coding part .. I hope someone knows what am I missing out here.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Are you sure the file is named selectivizr.js and not selectivizr-min.js like the module requires (i.e., did you rename it like you should have)?
- Check the permissions on the file, make sure that the server user or group (usually either apache or www-data) can access it. You could chmod 755 selectivizr.js to be sure.
- Flush Drupal's cache just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Crittenden is correct:

This is very likely because you copied selectivizr-min.js into your libraries folder.

The module is looking for selectivizr.js

Throw it in there, clear your caches and profit.

Answer (score 0):

just in case, i have the same problem on drupa 7.60 dev and solve it creating the folder and paste inside the folder the selectivizr.js file